# Page view visit path report always show "no data" in COBUB RAZOR

Tags: php, google-analytics, analytics, cobub-razor

I have included cobub razor SDK in my application it is working fine accept pageview & path report, it always displays "no data".

The table below this graph shows the data for activity. There is data in dim_activity table also.

I have executed the query given here.
 https://github.com/cobub/razor/issues/23

But have found no solution.

Comment: please see this question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22044759/no-data-shows-in-the-cobub-razor-admin

Comment: @Basbous The question that you mentioned in the comment has been deleted, do u have link for a solution ??

Comment: Javed, did you solve this? It would be helpful if you answered your own question if you did.

Comment: @samthebrand. Yes I have solved the problem. It's due to incorrect path specification.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the latest version of Cobub Razor.